# ¿Como realizar un calculo a travez de jquery utilizando el each?

Tags: jquery, each

Tengo el siguiente código que tiene el error de que cuando el usuario solo escribe un numero en una celda no aparece, el total solamente aparece cuando se llenan por lo menos dos celdas de lo contrario no me saca el total aunque solo ingrese un valor.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Por aquí dejo el código

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#DenominacionDetalle tbody tr td input#name", function () {
    var Cantidad = $(this).val();
    var ValorDenominacion = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[2].innerHTML;
    var Subtotal = parseFloat(Cantidad * ValorDenominacion);
    var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML);
    var filas = document.querySelectorAll("#DenominacionDetalle tbody tr");
    console.log('Cantidad')
    console.log(Cantidad)
    console.log('Valor')
    console.log(ValorDenominacion)
    console.log('SubTotal')
    console.log(Subtotal)
    console.log('----------')
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[3].innerHTML = Subtotal;
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''));
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //Grantotal
    if (!isNaN(document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML)) {
        document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = parseFloat(0);
    }
    else {
        var MontoInicial = 0;
        $("#DenominacionDetalle tbody tr:nth-child(-n+3) ").each(function () {
            MontoInicial += parseInt($(this).children("td:eq(3)").html());
            var totalfinal = document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = parseFloat(MontoInicial)
            document.getElementById("MontoInicial").innerHTML = parseFloat(MontoInicial)
            ///////////
            console.log('Total')
            console.log(MontoInicial)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SOes. ¿Podrías poner tu HTML? Te recomiendo también que visites [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla y revises [ask] y cómo hacer un [mcve]

Comment: por que quitaste el código?

Comment: revertí tu edición por que al modificar sin argumento lógico tu pregunta haces que pierda sentido, eso que hiciste no es válido

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no está mal, pero creo que el enfoque está algo perdido. Vas guardando fila por fila, además de que el evento lo generas por un ID, lo cual en estos casos no es lo recomendable.

Tambien desatas el evento en un keypress, lo cual tampoco es lo ideal, pienso que debe ser un keyup

te dejo un ejemplo

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#DenominacionDetalle input[name=qty]', function () {
        //prevenimos teclas indeseadas segun tu config
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault()
    }

    // guardamos todas las filas que requerimos
    // en este caso son todas las que tienen un input qty
    // ya que no queremos ni la primera ni la ultima
    let filas = $('#DenominacionDetalle tr input[name=qty]')
    let total = 0 //inicializamos el total en cero

    $.each(filas, function (i, v) {//recorremos las filas con $.each
      let qty = $(v).val()//guardamos el valor de cada input si esta vacio será cero
      let price = $(v).parents('tr').find('td')[2].innerHTML//buscamos el valor del producto
      let subtotal = parseFloat(qty * price) //obtenemos el subtotal
      total += subtotal //sumamos el subtotal al total general

      $(v).parents('tr').find('td')[3].innerHTML = subtotal //guardamos el subtotal en la celda 
    })

    $("#Total").text(total)//guardamos el total en la celda total
});
```

El ejemplo funcional en JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/s702Lrpc/2/